# How can I pipe Write-Output to Export-Csv?

Tags: powershell

I have the following "ping script" in which I would like to use an array along with the `Export-Csv` cmdlet to write the output to a CSV file rather than a txt file.

I first tried piping `Write-Output` to `Export-Csv` until reading that you cannot pipe strings to `Export-Csv` and must convert them into objects first.

I don't quite understand how to work with arrays in PowerShell.

```
Param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, position=0)][string]$csvfile
)

$ColumnHeader = "Hostname"

Write-Host "Reading file" $csvfile
$ipaddresses = Import-Csv $csvfile | Select-Object $ColumnHeader

Write-Host "Started Pinging.."
foreach ($ip in $ipaddresses) {
    if (Test-Connection $ip.("Hostname") -Count 1 -Quiet) {
        Write-Output $ip.("Hostname") "Ping succeeded." |
            Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\pingresults.txt" -Append
    } else {
        Write-Output $ip.("Hostname") "Ping failed." |
            Out-File -FilePath "C:\temp\pingresults.txt" -Append
    }
}

Write-Host "Pinging Completed."
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Of course you can pipe strings into `Export-Csv`. It's just that the result probably won't be what you expect, since `Export-Csv` exports the properties of the input objects as the fields of the output file. ;) String objects only have one property (`Length`), so you'd end up with an output file listing the lengths of the input strings.

To get an output CSV that lists the hostname (or IP address) along with the ping result you need to construct objects with 2 properties. The best way to do this in PowerShell is a pipeline:

```
Import-Csv $csvfile | ForEach-Object {
    New-Object -Type PSObject -Property ([ordered]@{
        Hostname = $_.Hostname
        Online   = [bool](Test-Connection $_.Hostname -Count 1 -Quiet)
    }
} | Export-Csv 'C:\path\to\output.csv' -NoType
```

Since you basically just want to add a property to the input data you can take an even simpler approach and add the ping result with a [calculated property](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx):

```
Import-Csv $csvfile |
    Select-Object Hostname,
        @{n='Online';e={[bool](Test-Connection $_.Hostname -Count 1 -Quiet)}} |
    Export-Csv 'C:\temp\pingresults.csv' -NoType
```

Appending to an array in a loop is not recommended, because appending essentially creates a new array with increased size, copies all elements from the old array, then adds the new elements to the new (empty) slots and releases the old array.

Comment: I think that you're probably better off importing things, running `Test-Connection` once against all of the IPs/Computer Names, and then parsing results afterwards. Pretty sure you're going to have less overhead that way than running `Test-Connection` once per machine.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers - I tried your 2nd example using the calculated property, however I only get the 'Hostname' and 'Online' column headers, but no other data gets populated.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician If total duration is an issue I would run the connection tests as jobs (runspaces or workflows would work too, of course), and collect the results before exporting them to a CSV.

Comment: @Heisenberg I doubt that. Please [update your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/44271522/edit) with sample input and the exact code you were using.

Comment: @Ansgar Wiechers - I tested it again and it works. Note to self: Testing is always better after morning coffee than at 1AM. Thanks so much. Do you have any suggestions for good PS learning resources that touch on this topic so I can dive a bit more in depth?

Comment: @Heisenberg [Master-PowerShell](http://community.idera.com/powershell/powertips/b/ebookv2) comes to mind. The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/powershell-scripting) is pretty extensive, too.

Answer (score 0):

you can create a $pingresult array as:

```
[string[]] $pingresult= @()
```

then to populate it simply do:

```
$pingresult += ip.("Hostname")," ping succeeded" -join""
```

or

```
$pingresult += ip.("Hostname")," ping failed" -join""
```

depending on the conditional.

finally you can export the array to csv:

```
convertfrom-csv -inputobject $pingresult | export-csv -path ...
```

Comment: Do I define the array just prior to the for loop?

Comment: yes, anywhere before the loop, after $columnheader lets say, to keep the definitions together

Comment: This won't do what the OP wants. At all. Piping a string array into `Export-Csv` creates an output CSV with the lengths of the individual strings in the array.

Comment: That still doesn't do what the OP wants, since hostname and response still aren't separate fields, and the first data row would become the CSV header. Please test your code before posting an answer.

Comment: To make your approach work you'd have to join hostname and response with the proper delimiter (`$ip.Hostname, 'ping succeeded' -join ','`) and add headers during the conversion (`ConvertFrom-Csv ... -Header 'Hostname', 'Response'`). But then you could also just drop the conversion entirely and write the strings directly to the output file (`'Hostname,Response', $pingresult | Set-Content output.csv`).